# Correct way to expose MutableLiveData as LiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

Consider the following ways to expose `MutableLiveData`:

**Method A**

```
class ThisViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _someData = MutableLiveData(true)
    val someData: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _someData
}

// Decompiled Kotlin bytecode

public final class ThisViewModelDecompiled extends ViewModel {

   private final MutableLiveData _someData = new MutableLiveData(true);

   @NotNull
   public final LiveData getSomeData() {
      return (LiveData)this._someData;
   }
}
```

**Method B**

```
class ThatViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _someData = MutableLiveData(true)
    val someData: LiveData<Boolean> = _someData
}

// Decompiled Kotlin bytecode

public final class ThatViewModelDecompiled extends ViewModel {

   private final MutableLiveData _someData = new MutableLiveData(true);

   @NotNull
   private final LiveData someData;

   @NotNull
   public final LiveData getSomeData() {
      return this.someData;
   }

   public ThatViewModel() {
      this.someData = (LiveData)this._someData;
   }
}
```

> Is there a reason to use Method B over Method A?

Comment: nice question (I mean really useful)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the *Java* perspective, *Method A* has one less field in the class, thus is "more" efficient. From the *Kotlin* perspective, *Method B* denotes a bit more clearly, that the non-mutable property is a direct reference to the mutable one. Also *Kotlin* is clever enough to locally access the field rather than the getter method.

> Is there a reason to use Method B over Method A?

In general is merely a matter of taste. Looking at it from a micro-optimization perspective it depends on whether or not you'd also use this reference within the class itself.

Answer (score 8):

Starting from Kotlin 1.4-M2 you can do simply:

```
private val myMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
val myLiveData : LiveData<String> by this::myMutableLiveData
```

The `this::` is unfortunately needed, otherwise does not compile.

I found this in [Igor Wojda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1211920/igor-wojda) which discusses other approaches. Unfortunately his answer in this question was deleted.

Comment: the link is not referring to the answer you mentioned, it's referring to Igor Wojda's profile.